# Переход к якорный ссылке с отступом

Tags: jquery

Как сделать отступ от фиксированного меню при наличии такого скрипта.
$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 500, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});
```

});

Comment: body{padding-top: heightMenuFixed px}

Comment: Спасибо, однако, так не пойдет. Необходимо встроить в скрипт отступ при переходе на якорь.